# Traversing to specific children - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-traversing

I have the following DOM structures given below and I would like to get to the hyperlink buttons (a) in both the scenarios. I have made both the header's (header1 and recordHeader1) clickable (cursor:pointer). So if I click on say anywhere (say if I click on the headerTitle) in header1 or (name, job_title)  in recordHeader1, I would like to find the hyperlink button and perform certain click functionality. There might be more of those scenario but in all the scenario's, there is a parent header like the one's given below and the parent header always has the hyperlink element somewhere in the DOM. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

**Scenario 1:**

```
<div class="header1">
  <a href="#" class="downArrow k-icon k-minus"></a> <!-- This element -->
  <img class="foundIcon" src="https://google.com">
  <div class="headerTitle">Contacts</div>
</div>
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
  <div class="recordNew">
      <div class="recordHeader1">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="arrowContainer">
              <a href="#" class="downArrow k-icon k-minus"></a> <!-- This element -->
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="nameContainer">
              <span class="name">John Doe </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span class="job-title">Marketing Professional </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**What I have tried?**

```
// This is a generic function that makes the header clickable based on any element click
function makeRowClickable() {
  $(".headerTitle, .name, .job_title, .foundIcon").on("click", function(e) {
    // doesn't seem to work and find the correct element
    console.log($(e.target).closest(".header1").find(".downArrow")); 
  });
}
```

Comment: you don't have an element with the `header1` class in your second example, so `.closest(".header1")` won't find anything

Comment: Yes agreed, that is just an example to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there always only one link in the clickable box?

Comment: No @MichaelKunst, there can be many, so I can't really target it with just an 'a'. However that 'a' always has a class called "downArrow" that I have mentioned in my question/example.

Comment: `.closest` will only find the closest ancestor that matches the selector, not siblings, ancestor siblings, or the children of ancestor siblings

Comment: Oh may be that's why it isn't working for me. But the find after the closest should take me to the correct element right?

Comment: If all of your comma-separated selectors whose `click` events you are manipulating have a common ancestor or one of several, you can use `.closest` to find that ancestor, and then `.find` to get a child anywhere inside that element.

Comment: So basically closest can't be used then because the header class can change and the position of that child element is not always in the same place. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
const headerClick = (e, header, downArrow) => {
  // programatically click on the anchor tag
  downArrow.click();
}

// get all .header1 elements
[...document.querySelectorAll('.header1')]

  // add all .recordHeader1 elements to the array
  .concat([...document.querySelectorAll('.recordHeader1')])

  // add event listener on each .header1 and .recordHeader1
  .forEach((header) => header.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // inside the click handler send the event, the header element, and its child downarrow element
    headerClick(e, header, header.querySelector('.downArrow'))

  }));
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, will this cater for any header element? My header element isn't always .header1.

Comment: you just need to keep concatenating selectors into your array. `querySelector` will traverse the dom tree for you.

Comment: Hi @Daniel_L, this does work however when I click on my other hyperlink elements, it performs the downArrow click as well. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: "when I click on my other hyperlink elements" yes...that is the default behavior of the `a` tag, correct?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want other `a` tags to perform this click as well as they open up other links. The elements that I mentioned above that should perform this click can be anything but another `a` tag. Is that possible?
Also the above code fails to work in IE :(. It fails on that `=>` operator, says syntax error and doesn't recognize it.

Comment: it would be much easier to assign an `onclick` event on the specific headers you want to trigger this business rule, rather than having to walk and filter out nodes.

Comment: Also @Daniel, how do I replace the arrow operator with a normal function? Its erroring in IE for some unknown reason.